# Parsing a json list without a key to the list

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse a json list like this into a java list. I get the json from an api call, so I'd rather not change the json.

```
[
   "4.14.2",
   "4.13.1",
   "4.12.2",
   "4.12.1",
    etc...
]
```

How would I be able to do it? This is what I have so far:

```
String val = JSON_STRING;
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst = new Gson().fromJson(val, lst.getClass());
```

Comment: Does it compile? Do you get errors? Is the output not what you want? what is the issue at hand?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What problem are you exactly facing?

Comment: I would think you'd use a JSON parser to parse it into a Java List of some sort.  What's the mystery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work, except that you should probably use a TypeToken instead of just a Class in order to supply Gson with the correct parameterized type.

```
List<String> lst = GSON.fromJson(val, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType());
```

(I'm assuming that the variable `GSON` is a suitably configured instance of the `Gson` class)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the JSON array & fetch list of String one-by-one from it. Just like this :-

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    String value = (String) jsonarray.get(i); // Type cast it to String type
}
```